# How to read files with numerical name with ascending order

Tags: sh

I have several (15) files with names : file1.out, file2.out, file3.out, ....,file15.out. I am reading each file and doing some calculation. Here is a sample.

```
    for file in file*.out; do
     echo $file
    done
```

But in this way the files are being read in the order file1.out, file10.out.... ,file15.out, file2.out...,file9.out. Is there any way to read these files in an ascending order i.e. file1.out then file2.out and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the amount of files you have, you can use a for integer loop

```
for i in $(seq 1 15); do
  echo "file$i.out"
done
```

For full POSIX compliance (`seq` is not a standard utility), use a `while` loop and an explicit counter

```
i=1
while [ "$i" -le 15 ]; do
    echo "file$i.out"
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: @chepner you are completely correct, I always fail to be full POSIX compliant

Answer (score 0):

### Rename your files

If you have less than 100 files you can use the following notation
file1.out => file01.out

### Change your sort algorithm

i.e. Use ls -v instead of file*.out

```
for i in `ls -v file*.out`; do
  echo $i;
done;
```

Comment: [Parsing the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is not a good suggestion.

Comment: IMHO it is thanks to the fact he is not using special character in his filename... Thanks for the link, that was interesting